# Complete the missing letter (require Web knowledge)

Tags: letter-sequence

Given this sequence of letters:

```
 _, B, G, C, R, M, Y, _
```

What is the first and last letter?

hint 1

> each letter represent a color

hint 2

> C represents the color Cyan and M for Magenta

The answer is responded, but try to find the sequence behind it. Explain Why

> the sequence is related a order of HTML Hex Color Codes.

Comment: Hmm, no luck so far. Is it trivia related? I.e. do we need to know about a sport to answer it?

Comment: no, its not about a sport

Comment: first is A right ? :)

Comment: @user2408578 no :(

Comment: I'm thinking colour models on first glance.

Comment: is it related to gaming ?....and also few secods back i saw a hint to be added where is that ? :)

Comment: @Christian I mean trivia in general, not just sport.

Comment: @Christian can we re-arrange sequence of letters?

Comment: @MokshShah no, it's is a sequence

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As HumphreyTheHater stated,

> Black and White, or B and W, respectively

But why are these the proper letters?

> Black = 0x000000
>  
> Blue    = 0x0000FF
>  
> Green   = 0x00FF00
>  
> Cyan    = 0x00FFFF
>  
> Red     = 0xFF0000
>  
> Magenta = 0xFF00FF
>  
> Yellow  = 0xFFFF00
>  
> White   = 0xFFFFFF
>  
> These colors follow the standard binary counting system, using 00 for 0 and FF for 1:
>  
> 000
>  
> 001
>  
> 010
>
>  011
>  
> 100
>  
> 101
>  
> 110
>  
> 111

Comment: correct answer :D

Comment: btw, this question was bad? beacuse I got 2 negative votes, it's my first question and I want know if there is something bad .

Comment: @Christian I would think the main reason would be because it was vague. You could have cryptically referenced the fact that they were web based colors. After seeing that and doing some pondering was when it clicked for me, but that's because I'm a developer and stare at values like this every day.

Answer (score 1):

> B & W

representing

> Black and white? Seems like the two obvious missing 'colours' from cyan, yellow, red, blue, green

Comment: yes it's the answer, i give the second hint but it's didn't need

Comment: so how this sequence would be?
 B, B, G, C, R, M, Y, W ? B is already there but...

Comment: @Humphreythehater but there is a sequence behind this, do you know?

Comment: @MokshShah B is repeated, but the answer is B, B, G, C, R, M, Y, W

Comment: @Christian Then what does that 2nd B represent ?

Comment: B=Blue and Black

Comment: @MokshShah first B = Black, second B = Blue

Comment: But couldn't understand the logic ...huh

Comment: @MokshShah I added  the hint for the sequence

Comment: if you down voted can you tell me why, I'm new here and I want a feedback.